# Glyphicons can't apply the website in bootstrap 4.5.0

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-rest-framework, bootstrap-modal

bootstrap 4.5.0 can't use Glyphicons in the old version way
the glyphicons doesn't show on my website ,is there anyone knows the new method to apply the glyphicon in 4.5.0 version???

```
<p>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
this is the line 1
</p>
```

Comment: the icons are not in bootstrap, you have to use an external library to import them such font awesome, what library are you using?

Comment: i just use this css file : <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: it is only bootstrap, in that library you can't find any icon, you have to use another library like font awesome or material icons

Answer (score 1):

according the documentation you bootstrap 4 doesn't include icons, you have to use an external library

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/extend/icons/

let's start with front awesome

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

here is the gallery with free icons

https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free

there is a CDN:

https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

but I don't know how it works, I ever downloaded them

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```